# ORACLE - String to number

Tags: string, oracle, numbers

I have a little problem with a column on a table.
The column is a Varchar named "prize".
The datas are something like:

```
00008599
00004565
00001600
etc...
```

They have to become:

```
85.99
45.65
16.00
etc...
```

I have tried with to_number function but it doesnt work.
Something like:

```
SELECT to_number(prize, '999999.99') FROM TABLE
```

The error is: ORA-01722

Comment: Do you have values in the column that aren't pure numbers? You can check with something like 'not regexp_like(prize, '^[0-9]+$')`

Comment: If you can (after finding the data that doesn't conform), you should update your data model so that prize is stored as number and even preferably number(n,2) for some suitable value of n.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use LTRIM to get rid of leading zeroes and divide by 100:

```
SELECT to_number(ltrim(prize, '0')) / 100 FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you. I was using this instruction that involve string functions but your is better

to_number( SUBSTR(prize,0,5)||'.'||SUBSTR(prize,6,2)) as realPrize

Answer (score 5):

Please notice that you yourself have to handle the fact that the string is 100 times to great. Easiest way should be something like this:

```
SELECT to_number(prize)/100 FROM TABLE
```